# Data Treatment in concatenating some missing numbers

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

When I passed the data to an Excel sheet, it cut of all the extra zeros that come before the numbers, but some of them actually started with zeros, so some rows are lacking zeros.

I already cut the zeros off:

```
import pandas as pd

cpfs = pd.read_excel('cpfs.xlsx')
cpf = cpfs.values.tolist()

zeros = (cpfs != 0).any(axis=1)
semZeros_cpfs = cpfs.loc[zeros]
```

Now, I need to fix the data missing a zero or two in the beginning of the row:

> 46456402832
> 30116096837
> 7986710411
> 39785948897

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to mitigate this by preserving zeroes at the import?

```
cpfs = pd.read_excel(file, dtype={'column_with_desired_zeros': str})
```

To add leading zeroes to the numbers that are already imported you can use `zfill`:

```
str(semZeros_cpfs).zfill(11)
```

11 being the length of the number you need.

Note that dtype neest to be `'string'` and not `'int'` in oder to add leading zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't understand the use of zfill, tho, since my output with it was an empty string. I've put it inside a variable, and that was the response.